# Efficiently compute the dot product on the last dimension of an array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-einsum

What is the fastest way to compute the dot product on the last dimension of a multidimensional ndarray?

For the moment I am doing that:

```py
import numpy as np

a=np.reshape(np.arange(90),[3,3,2,5])
b=np.reshape(np.arange(90),[3,3,2,5])
# for the sake of simplicity, a and b are the same for this example

ab=(a*b).sum(axis=-1)
```

I think that `einsum` could be of use here, but I struggle to apply it to my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generic ndim arrays to get sum-reductions along last axis -

```
np.einsum('...i,...i->...',a,b)
```

Alternative with `np.matmul` -

```
np.matmul(a[...,None,:],b[...,None])[...,0,0]
```

Note : On Python 3.x `np.matmul` could be replaced by `@ operator`.

Comment: Thanks! this works perfectly! Using `%timeit` indicates that it is twice as fast with `einsum` than with the `sum` that I originally proposed. `matmul` is a little bit slower than `einsum` but faster than the sum.